# Using CSS to animate image within box

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to animate an image when hovered.

The image should at all times stay within the confines of the box. It should have a little opacity. When the image is hovered, it is zoomed and the opacity is brought to 1, all over a short duration of 0.3s instead of all at once.

The CSS I've written is:

```
    .t_box {
    width: 250px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 5px solid #FF0000;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 40;
}

.t_box img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.t_box img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: scale(1.5);

    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

As it is now, the opacity fades in/out at 0.3 seconds, but the image scale is all at once and does not stay within the confines of the wrapped box.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uungtt8q/

Comment: I'm no expert with CSS3 transitions, but is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uungtt8q/2/?

Comment: Yes it is, only that the image should not expand out of the box, even when it is hovered.

Comment: Ah, so like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uungtt8q/3/?

Comment: OK, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need the transition rules on the normal state of the image, not on both the normal state and the hover state:

```
.t_box img {
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;vertical-align:bottom
}
.t_box img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uungtt8q/3/)**

To hide the image from leaving the parent div, just add `overflow: hidden` to the div:

```
.t_box {
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 5px solid #FF0000;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 40;  
    overflow:hidden;
}
```